# MySQL GroupBy with null/zero results

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently writing a ticket system that has three tables

one for users:

```
users
    +----+-----------+----------+
    | ID | FirstName | LastName |
    +----+-----------+----------+
    |  1 | First     | User     |
    |  2 | Second    | User     |
    |  3 | Third     | User     |
    |  4 | Fourth    | User     |
    |  5 | Fifth     | User     |
    +----+-----------+----------+
```

one for tickets:

```
ticket
    +----+---------------+
    | ID | TicketSubject |
    +----+---------------+
    |  1 | Ticket #1     |
    |  2 | Ticket #2     |
    |  3 | Ticket #3     |
    |  4 | Ticket #4     |
    +----+---------------+
```

and one to assign users to tickets to action (can be more than one user per ticket):

```
ticket_assigned
    +----+----------+--------+
    | ID | TicketID | UserID |
    +----+----------+--------+
    |  1 |        1 |      1 |
    |  2 |        1 |      2 |
    |  3 |        2 |      1 |
    |  4 |        3 |      5 |
    |  5 |        3 |      3 |
    +----+----------+--------+
```

I'm trying to create a summary to show each user, and how many tickets they have assigned to them, example:

```
+------------+-------+
|    Name    | Count |
+------------+-------+
| First      |     2 |
| Second     |     1 |
| Third      |     1 |
| Fourth     |     0 |
| Fifth      |     1 |
| Unassigned |     2 |
+------------+-------+
```

Note that the last entry is "unassigned", this is the number of records in the ticket table that DONT appear in the ticket_assigned table (thus being, unassigned). Also further note that user "Fourth" is zero, in that that user has no records in the ticket_assigned table.

Here is the current MySQL query I am using:

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
      WHEN users.FirstName IS NULL 
      THEN 'Unassigned' 
      ELSE users.FirstName 
   END as 'UserName',
   COUNT(*) as 'TicketCount' 
FROM tickets 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ticket_assigned ON tickets.ticket_id = ticket_assigned.ticket_id 
LEFT OUTER  JOIN users ON ticket_assigned.user_id = users.user_id 
GROUP BY ticket_assigned.user_id 
ORDER BY UserName;
```

Problem with this is that it's not showing any of the users that don't feature in the ticket_assigned table, I'm essentially getting this:

```
+------------+-------+
|    Name    | Count |
+------------+-------+
| First      |     2 |
| Second     |     1 |
| Third      |     1 |
| Fifth      |     1 |
| Unassigned |     2 |
+------------+-------+
```

Is anyone able to assist and tell me how I can modify my query to include users that have no records in the ticket_assigned table? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` with a subquery to aggregate tickets:

```
SELECT t1.FirstName,
       COALESCE(t2.ticket_count, 0) AS num_tickets
FROM users t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT UserID, COUNT(*) AS ticket_count
    FROM ticket_assigned
    GROUP BY UserID
) t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.UserID
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Unassigned', COUNT(*)
FROM tickets t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tickets_assigned ta
                  WHERE ta.ticketId = t.id)
```

Comment: @AndrewMilici Updated.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, I think you need a `left join` and `union all`:

```
select u.id, u.firstname, count(ta.userId) as num_tickets
from users u left join
     tickets_assigned ta
     on ta.userId = u.id
group by u.id, u.firstname
union all
select NULL, 'Unassigned', count(*)
from tickets t
where not exists (select 1
                  from tickets_assigned
                  where ta.ticketId = t.id
                 );
```

I included the `u.id` in the aggregations.  I'm uncomfortable just aggregating (and reporting) by first name, because different people frequently have the same first name, even in a relatively small group.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    u2.Firstname, IFNULL(tmp.count, 0) AS count
FROM users u2 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT u.id, u.Firstname, COUNT(1) as count
    FROM ticket_assigned ta 
    LEFT JOIN ticket t ON t.id = ta.ticketID
    LEFT JOIN users u ON  u.id = ta.userID
    GROUP BY u.id
    ) tmp ON tmp.id = u2.id
UNION 

SELECT
    'Unassigned', count(1) AS count 
FROM ticket
    WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT ticketid FROM ticket_assigned)
```